# Fortran: 10 nested loops slow with ending print statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have some code that runs in about a second, but slows to a standstill after a very minor edit.

The following code runs in 1 sec with gfortran -O3

```
  program loop
          implicit none
          integer n, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10
          parameter(n=18) !<=== most important
          integer i,array(n)
          real cal
          real p1(n)

  do i=1,n
     p1(i)=float(i)/10.
  enddo

  write (*,1) p1
```

1   `format (10(f6.2))`

```
  cal=0.
  i1=0
  i2=0

  do i1=1,n
  !write(*,1) cal !<-- too slow if write here
     do i2=1,n
        do i3=1,n
           do i4=1,n
              do i5=1,n
                 do i6=1,n
                    do i7=1,n
                       do i8=1,n
                          do i9=1,n
                            do i10=1,n
     cal=p1(i1) !<-- perfectly happy to compute, as long as I don't write
     array(i1)=i1+i2
                            enddo
                          enddo
                       enddo
                    enddo
                 enddo
              enddo
           enddo
        enddo
     enddo
     !write(*,1) cal !<-- and too slow if write here too!
   enddo

   write(*,*) (array(i),i=1,n)

   stop
   end
```

First of all, forgive me for the mixture of f77 & 90. It's a boiled down example based on a real problem. However, the salient point is that if the parameter **n=17**, everything's fine. The second to last write statement can be uncommented, and the code runs in about a second. However, with n=18, the code slows to a halt... unless, if the second to last write statement is commented out, it runs in a second with **n=18**.

In the two tests, there are a total of **17^10** and **18^10** iterations total. I have been unable to find any indication there is a limit on the number of total iterations. I keep thinking 18^10 must be exceeding some limit, but I do not know what. And why would the print statement matter for **n=18** but not **n=17**? More info: Mem usage is near zero. **CPU is i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz**.

If I use **-O0** the code always runs extremely slowly.

Comment: 18^10 is a huge number! You can't expect that to be too quick. If it is, something is wrong (and Yossarian explains what that is).

Comment: Where you have your write, it should not be a big deal, So I am wandering if your example contains everything to reproduce your problem. Even though the most inner iteration runs 18^10 times, the outer loop that contains your I/O runs only 18 times. Can you run and time this very example and provide us with the exact runtime?

Answer (score 4):

With gfortan 4.8.3, I don't see much runtime difference between including the `write` statements and leaving them out, but there is a huge difference between `-O3` and `-O0`. The reason for this is because the compiler is able to massively optimise the loops with `-O3`, which it doesn't do with `-O0`. The compiler can essentially work out the answer in advance and completely omit the loops. With the higher optimisations, the compiler can also use more advanced features of your CPU, which work faster.

Putting the `write` statements inside the loop somewhat disrupts the ability of the compiler to aggressively optimise the loops, meaning it can no longer omit them entirely, which leads to the slower runtimes you're seeing. You are probably using an older version of gfortran which doesn't cope very well with this situation.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took some of their time to respond. I appreciate it. I do realize optimizations unroll loops, keep the pipeline efficiently stuffed, etc. I do know 18^10 (if you look at processor GHz & #instructions per cycle, well it comes out to several hours of runtime). Here is what I do not understand: Take this line  of code:

Comment: @JFSebastian This is less a case of loop unrolling and more just completely replacing the loop with something much simpler. When you add the `write` statements, it has to keep some of the loop. Also, the comments aren't great for code, please edit it into your question.

Comment: Yep. 18^10 operations, actually performed, should take hours (even with the pipeline efficiently stuffed, etc.) Here was the problem: With n=17 & -O3, the run took <1 sec. Leaving all the same except n=18, the run slowed like -O0 was specified. (Placing a write stmt a few loops in showed ~4 lines of output/sec -- it'd have taken hours to finish.) I tried a newer gfortran (5.1.0) as suggested. All writes uncommented & n=320, it ran in 1 sec. Odd that n=17 & n=18 had  given different results with v4.47. It must be a vagary of older gfortran. (Ifort was reported "worse" in this regard.)

Comment: I had accidentally hit post and then editing timed out. The immediately-above post was my post.

Comment: It's been clear all along that the literal running of all computations would take hours, not 1 s, that the compiler is smart enough to cut to the chase (and cut out loops -- there's no other way to run that fast given the GHz of the machine and # computations etc.). It was just odd that n=17 vs 18 was the cutoff between running smart and not comprehending the opportunity for skipping loops.

Comment: Actually, I think the compiler skips explicitly defined computations. It can somehow read that the computations are trivial and reads the indices, and turns it into a simple calculation. I bet if the computations were more substantive and not simply a function of indicies, i.e. inherently very serial, it would slow right back down.